# Gradle build to infinity whitout errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a problem with gradle who builds endlessly without errors. I've tried quite a trick to find on the web but none has managed to solve my problem. I have this problem after install windows 10 ...

[image: Screenshot]

log : http://paste.ubuntu.com/12281101/

Comment: Try to get the log and see if there is something wrong `On toolbar -> Help Menu -> Show log in explore `. Post here if you dont have an idea of it

Comment: @Panther I can not access the menu. The log that is in .AndroidStudio / system / log / idea.log?